# Why does this optimization cause my merge sort to fail?

Tags: c, sorting, optimization, merge, mergesort

I'm working on a non-recursive merge sort, and I've come up with an optimization that will speed it up somewhat.  The gist is that instead of merging into a temporary buffer and then copying it back into the data location each time, I instead merge first in one direction, then the other.  This should work perfectly, since the buffers are the same size and the data is the same.

However, when I try this, my array isn't completely sorted.  There are a few items, sometimes at the end and sometimes in the middle, that are out of place.  I've included the functions that I'm using to test my code in the example below.

I tried as best I could to make an MWE, but there are a couple of helper functions that are required for testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MIN(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (y) : (x))
#define OPTIMIZE true // if true, then merge in alternating directions

void merge(int* src, int* dest, size_t start, size_t mid, size_t end);
void merge_sort(int* data, size_t length);

/* MERGESORT IMPLEMENTATION {{{1 */

void merge(int* src, int* dest, size_t start, size_t mid, size_t end) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = start, j = mid, k = start; i < mid && j < end; k++) {
        if (src[i] > src[j]) {
            dest[k] = src[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            dest[k] = src[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (; i < mid; i++, k++) {
        dest[k] = src[i];
    }
    for (; j < end; j++, k++) {
        dest[k] = src[j];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int* data, size_t length) {
    int* buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int swap = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = data[i];
    }

#if OPTIMIZE
    for (size_t step = 1; step < length; step *= 2, swap = !swap) {
        int* src = swap ? buffer : data;
        int* dest = swap ? data : buffer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length - step; i += (step * 2)) {
            merge(src, dest, i, i + step, MIN(length, i + (step * 2)));
        }
    }
    if (swap) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
#else
    for (size_t step = 1; step < length; step *= 2, swap = !swap) {
        int* src = data;
        int* dest = buffer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length - step; i += (step * 2)) {
            merge(src, dest, i, i + step, MIN(length, i + (step * 2)));
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
#endif

    free(buffer);
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS {{{1 */

void check_sorted(int* data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i] != i) {
            printf("%ld: %d\n", i, data[i]);
        }
    }
}

void shuffle(int* data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        size_t index = rand() % (i + 1);
        int temp = data[index];
        data[index] = data[i];
        data[i] = temp;
    }
}

/* MAIN {{{1 */

int main() {
    size_t length = 200;
    int* data = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = (int)i;
    }
    shuffle(data, length);

    merge_sort(data, length);
    check_sorted(data, length);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's how I would debug this. Use a smaller `length` (values between 8 and 15 should be sufficient). After calling `shuffle`, save the array. Then sort and check. If the check fails, print the saved array. That gives you an example array that you know is going to fail. Use that array, and step through the code with a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: There's a bug in the `check_sorted` function: `i < length - 1` should be `i < length`. The code isn't checking the last element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appear to be working. Fixes noted in comments:

```
void merge_sort(int* data, size_t length) {
    int* buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int swap = false;
    /*                                  ** removed the initial copy */

#if OPTIMIZE
    for (size_t step = 1; step < length; step *= 2, swap = !swap) {
        int* src = swap ? buffer : data;
        int* dest = swap ? data : buffer;
        size_t i;                       /* fix, using i in 2nd loop */
        for (i = 0; i < length - step; i += (step * 2)) {  /* fix (removed size_t) */
            merge(src, dest, i, i + step, MIN(length, i + (step * 2)));
        }
        for( ; i < length; i++)         /* fix, copy single run if present */
            dest[i] = src[i];           /* fix, copy single run if present */
    }
    if (swap) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
#else
```

---

Alternate fix:

```
    for (size_t step = 1; step < length; step *= 2, swap = !swap) {
        int* src = swap ? buffer : data;
        int* dest = swap ? data : buffer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i += (step * 2)) {                        /* fix */
            merge(src, dest, i, MIN(length, i+step), MIN(length, i+(step * 2))); /* fix */
        }
```

Comment: This absolutely works, although I'm not sure I conceptually understand why.  Perhaps it's because, since the array isn't always a power of two, the merges are of different sizes, and by alternating some detritus gets left over.  Regardless, that fixed my issue. Thanks and accepted!

Comment: @WalterMays - I added an alternate fix. (using i < length instead of i < length-step and MIN(length, i+step).

Comment: I much prefer that alternate fix. Thanks for this answer, it's really helpful.